# How can I get the Workgroup name of a computer using C#?

Tags: c#, workgroup

I've read about getting it with the Environment class, but can't find it.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with WMI; add a reference to System.Management.dll and a using statement for System.Management namespace, then call the following code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = 
  new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", @"SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get()) {
  Console.WriteLine(mo["Workgroup"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Hans. At first it had the escaped backslash, then I edited it to make them verbatim strings but the syntax highlighting disappeared. When I changed it back (I like seeing my code in color,) I didn't get it quite right. Still no highlighting though, I see?

Answer (score 7):

A way based on the Jono response, but shorter:

```
public static string GetWorkGroup()
{
    ManagementObject computer_system = new ManagementObject(
                string.Format(
                "Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'",
                Environment.MachineName));

    object result = computer_system["Workgroup"];
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried this using the WMI options suggested here, but it turned out to be excruciatingly slow (sometimes over 5 seconds) on my machine (and several others in my office).  What ended up working for me was using the API call "NetGetJoinInformation" ([PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetGetJoinInformation.html)).  The API call returns very quickly for me and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetGetJoinInformation.html) for an example. You will have to use P/Invoke.